# How to keep UIButton back to its position after dismissing keyboard in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, uibutton

I have a UIButton at bottom of the screen and when the user types in UITextView that button gets attached to the keypad (input accessory view) like the screenshot I have attached  (violet arrow mark). Now once the keyboard is dismissed then I want this button to be at the bottom of the screen instead of the input accessory view (check yellow arrow mark flow).[image]

Here is the code I used

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    confirmButtonUI()
    subscribeToShowKeyboardNotifications()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
 }



   func confirmButtonUI() {
        confirmButton.layer.cornerRadius = 20.0
        confirmButton.layer.shadowRadius = 1.0
        confirmButton.layer.shadowColor = UIColor(displayP3Red: 33/255, green: 68/255, blue: 27/255, alpha: 0.18).cgColor
        confirmButton.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor(displayP3Red: 164/255, green: 208/255, blue: 208/255, alpha: 1).cgColor
        confirmButton.isEnabled = false
        confirmButton.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 2.0)
        confirmButton.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
        confirmButton.layer.masksToBounds = false
    }
    




   func subscribeToShowKeyboardNotifications() {

       NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: 
       #selector(keyboardWillShow(_:)), name: 
       UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
      
       NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: 
       #selector(keyboardWillHide(_:)), name: 
       UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)

  }



 @objc func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: Notification) {
        let userInfo = notification.userInfo
        confirmButton.layer.cornerRadius = 0.0
        othersTextField.inputAccessoryView = confirmButton

        let keyboardSize = userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue
        _ = keyboardSize.cgRectValue.height
        let animationDuration = userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! Double
        UIView.animate(withDuration: animationDuration) {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }



@objc func keyboardWillHide(_ notification: Notification) {
        othersTextField.inputAccessoryView = nil
        confirmButtonBottomConstrains.constant = 57   //Crash here

        let userInfo = notification.userInfo
        let animationDuration = userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! Double
        UIView.animate(withDuration: animationDuration) {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }

In this method its crashing on this line " confirmButtonBottomConstrains.constant = 57 "
```

What i was doing is once the keyboard is dismissing am making inputAccessoryView as nil and then am trying to use the bottom nslayout constraint for the button to set as 57 (like i set in UI)  but this line crashing with following message

```
Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value
```

Please help me to solve this

Comment: The error states that `confirmButtonBottomConstrains` is empty, meaning that you have not assigned/linked the constraint. See if you have linked the constraint to the storyboard or if you have done it programmatically, see if you have set the constraint properly

Comment: yes i did, but i think when I moved the button to inputaccessory view of textview this constraint might be gone

Comment: Does it work now?

Answer (score 1):

#### Problem

You haven't provided details about whether the view is setup programmatically or in a storyboard. I am assuming it was a storyboard (since I do not see any view initialization).

Also, I am not sure how you got the button to stick as an `inputAccessoryView`. I couldn't replicate this behavior. In your case, setting a view that is already part of the view hierarchy as an accessory view might be causing the undocumented behavior where existing constraints are removed.

#### Solution

Instead of using the **same** button, you can very easily create a **new** button and assign it as an `inputAccessoryView` to your `UITextField` / `UITextView`.

This would eliminate problems with missing constraints since the original view is never changed.

It would look something like this, (in addition to your disabled button):

[image]

##### Code to setup input accessory view:

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setupInputAccessory()
    othersTextField.delegate = self
}

func setupInputAccessory(){
    let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: 44.0)
    let btn = UIButton(frame: frame)
    
    btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.purple
    btn.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
    btn.setTitle("Confirm", for: .normal)
    btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(accessoryConfirmTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    
    othersTextField.inputAccessoryView = btn
}

@objc func accessoryConfirmTapped(){
    othersTextField.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

#### Notes

The above is a code snippet in addition to your existing code.  However, with this approach I have removed the following from your code.

1. Changing the `othersTextField.inputAccessoryView` in keyboard events.
2. Confirm Button bottom constraint.

But the gist of it is, I have two separate buttons. One that is setup by the storyboard and the other setup in code and attached to the TextField. I do not share the button with the controller's view and as the input accessory.

I have the complete solution in a [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/Thisura98/accessory-view-test) if you want to check it out further.